# Как перенести EAV на jsonb в postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, eav

В EAV структура следующая(Сократил сущности для простоты понимания)

Item

-id

Attribute

-id

-name

-is_filter

Value

- id
- attribute_id
- value

Item_Value

-item_id

-value_id

Я хочу перенести это в сущность Item и хранить в jsonb.
Но возникают проблема. Одна из них целостность данных.
В случае использования EAV мы меняем Value в таблице Value и это значение измениться для всех Item. Но как это реализовать в jsonb ? и перенести эту струтуру

Comment: Несколько странное требование или название таблицы. Обычно value подразумевают, что их изменение сразу везде не требуется. Ну да ладно, не суть. в json вы такого не сделаете. Вопрос в том, а зачем нужен json ? Если для ускорения выборки, то тогда можно оставить и текущую структуру и добавить колонку в jsonb которую менять триггерами на изменении всех таблиц

Comment: @Mike прочитал кучу статей, что jsonb использовать лучше, чем EAV. В целом структура jsonb у меня такая, есть несколько динамических полей, с ними проблем нет, они записываются и есть 4 поля постоянные, по ним нужно будет делать фильтр. Например Цвет: Красный и т.д.. И тут возникла проблема 1) Нужно выбирать все значения для фильтра на сайте, что наклодные расходы, если миллион строк. Как-то глупо в каждом товаре напрямую писать его цвет и дублировать

Comment: А, вы в Value не показали, что там еще и название есть, поэтому мне странным и показалось. EAV для поиска и поддержания целостности данных гораздо эффективнее, чем все атрибуты сваленные в json. А вот скорость выборки товара со всеми параметрами становится гораздо хуже из за кучи join. Поэтому если вам нужна и скорость поиска и целостность и скорость выборки, то данные приходится дублировать. Писать и для поиска в EAV и для выборки в саму запись. Триггера позволяют все это дело держать синхронным.

Comment: В принципе есть еще один подход. id значения у вас уникально и при этом сразу говорит о виде атрибута. Можно делать не jsonb (который кстати занимает очень много места в записи, что то же плохо сказывается на скорость. А поставить расширение intarray https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/intarray сделать в item поле int[] и хранить в нем id всех значений атрибутов, которые присущи данной записи. Поиск по полю может быть очень быстрым, даже по набору из нескольких фильтров (в описании расширения об этом подробно написано).

Comment: @Mike Проблема в jsonb как мне выбрать все фильтры мои - поля, и как проверять фильтер это или нет. Раньше была таблица chatacteristics где были все характеристики и там было поле is_filter